# Connecting C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I've been writing a program in C++ and noticed there is a library in C# that someone else wrote that I would like to link in to my code.... but I'm not sure how to do that. Can someone suggest something? Doubt this matters, but I'm using Windows 7 with MSVC2010.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the library do? Maybe there is a C++ library for that.

Comment: It's a voice recognition library, but I'd also just like to know the answer to this question for the future, regardless of whether is another library for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're familiar with COM you could [access the .NET library through COM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsfww439.aspx). If the library doesn't provide COM interop out of the box you could write a wrapper around it using C# and expose that through COM.

If you're going to pull in a .NET library you should be aware that it requires a .NET runtime which may take up valuable resources. If you ware building the application in C++ for performance reasons, maybe you're better off porting the parts of the library you need to C++.

Comment: Example code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106033/how-do-i-call-a-net-assembly-from-c-c

Answer (score 6):

You can try compiling your C++ program in C++/CLI mode. Then the compiler will produce a .NET executable which can create C# objects and use their methods.

C++/CLI is discussed here: [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Comment: +1. Note that if you do this though you'll have to mark your assembly as unsafe as marking your code as safe requires that there be no unmanaged code.

Comment: It sounds like that would require refactoring of the C# code? Is that the case? Also, can I compile other programs such as Qt with C++/CLI?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything on the C# side, as you can create and use .NET objects in C++/CLI, something like:

    `DotNetClass^ aClass = gcnew DotNetClass();
    aClass->SomeMethod();`

You would probably have trouble converting libraries such as QT into C++/CLI. However you can set individual files in a project to compile in C++/CLI mode and leave the others as normal C++. Visual Studio will manage the transition for you.

This means you can create a C++/CLI wrapper around the .NET library, and keep the rest of the project in regular C++.