# How to run a console process inside a c++ console

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, console-application

So basically I designed this c# application that has a cool design, but instead of remaking it to put back into c++ I want to make my life easier and just make it run inside of a c++ console application. The problem is I can only figure out a way to run the application in the c++ console as an external process and not actually embedded in the c++ console (they are both console applications) Is there any way that I can start the c# console inside the c++ console?

This is my code on c++
`int result = system(location);`

If anyone has any ideas, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: In other words you're trying to link C# and C++, yes?

Comment: Yes, I am but the c# has to be in the c++ process.

Comment: Okay, well I'e never done that before, but a good place to start seems to be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3029031/10957435).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13293888/10957435) also seems useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using the `system()` command in your question, I'm assuming you're okay with me using it in my solution. In which case, just resort to the Batch (CMD) commands for starting a process in the current window.

First, you'll need to compile the C# code. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553155/11073848) explains how to do that in detail. If you want to do this inside a C++ program, simply wrap the compile command in the `system()` command (e.g. `system("/* path to csc.exe */ \t:exe \out:App.exe App.cs");`).

After that, simply wrap the name of the exe in another `system()` command (e.g. `system(App.exe)`).

So, if I had a cs script named "Books.cs," here's how I can compile (if needed) and run from C++:

```cpp
// PATH_TO_CSC should be replaced with the path to csc.exe on your machine

int main()
{
    system("PATH_TO_CSC \t:exe \out:Books.exe Books.cs");
    system(Books.exe);
}
```

Note, for this to work, your working directory will have to be the same as the C# script. This is untested on my end for C# programs, but I was able to run a C++ executable console app that did not open a new window. Another executable should have a similar outcome.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out today. And just to make sure will this allow me to use the c# console inside the c++ console? Thanks so much.