# how to port VB code in C++

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net, winapi

I want to use VB.NET code in win32 (C++) (I dont want to convert my code). I have heard about wrapping VB code in COM but i don't know how to do it. Also, I am not aware if there is an alternative (or any better) way of porting the code.

Any help is appereciated.

**Update:** I created a class library in vb and saved it as a dll after setting the comvisible attribute to true, then imported it in my c++ project and accessed the interfaces via COM

**thank you everone for helping me out !!!!!!! **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call .NET code directly from a native C++ application, so there is some work involved.

Of course, your question leaves us guessing at *why* you're wanting to do this, but unless you are still going to be using the library from a .NET application, I would be a strong advocate in favor of porting it (like your title suggests) to C++.

But if you don't want to do this, you have a couple of other options:

1. Write a wrapper around the VB.NET code using C++/CLI. This would probably be the simpler solution, especially if you're reasonably familiar with both the VB.NET and C++ languages.
2. Expose the VB.NET methods you need as COM functions, using the [`<ComVisible(true)>` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx). This is going to be a bit trickier to get going, especially if you're uncomfortable or unfamiliar with COM programming in C++. It's too much to explain in a Stack Overflow answer; investigate purchasing a good book on COM programming. And although you're using VB.NET, the steps are basically the same for C#, for which you'll have much better luck finding [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106033/how-do-i-call-a-net-assembly-from-c-c).

Comment: There should be automatic translators from VB.net to C# methinks that could also help you understand the equivalence.

Comment: @Cody, thnx for the 'examples' link. After a little more research, i got it workin'

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly port VB into C++, but if you are looking to just switch to a more powerful language and still use the GUI libraries, you can check out C#. It uses very similar code, and a quick google search provided me this program: [C# converter](http://converter.telerik.com/). If you really need C++, you could probably then convert the C# code to C++, but there really wouldn't be a need to since C# is VERY close to C++. Just googling that I found this: [C++ converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_CPlusPlus_Converter_Details.html).

I hope this will help you.

Comment: C# is VB.NET with curly braces. C# is no more powerful than VB.NET. They both compile to MSIL.

Comment: The similarities between C# and C++ are superficial (i.e. syntactical) only. You'll spend most of your time re-writing the .NET libraries in native C++.